# php-cgi dies quietly every few hours in low traffic

Tags: php, gentoo, fcgi

php-cgi -v

```
   PHP 5.2.11-pl1-gentoo (cgi-fcgi) (built: Dec 21 2009 09:10:29)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

System info

```
dev-lang/php-5.2.11-r1
gentoo 10.1
```

Update: I' just compiled PHP with the minimal USE flags turned on. Seems better now. Let's wait a bit longer.

Comment: Good to know...

Comment: I'm certainly going to sleep better at night now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' just compiled PHP with the minimal USE flags turned on. No crash again for two days.

BTW: It seems the memory was too small, it was 256MB. Now on a server with 512MB memory, the PHP works well with default USE flags.

Answer (score 1):

Well php does this sometimes, you might want to set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS environment variable, which will force php to kill itself after some number of requests and being reexecuted, so the problem won't appear.